# Given $o(a)=5$, prove $C(a)=C(a^{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, self-learning

> Given $o(a)=5$, prove $C(a)=C(a^{3})$

At this point I would like a **hint** rather than a full solution. I know we are given $a^{5}=e$ and that we wish to prove this implies that $C(a) =\{ x \in G:xa=ax \}=\{x \in G : xa^{3}=a^{3}x \} =C(a^{3})$. However, I can't around as to how exactly I am going to show the latter.

I take a stab at it:

\begin{align}
ax&=eax \\
&=a^{5}ax \tag{$o(a)=5$} \\
&=(aaaaa)ax \tag{Definition of power} \\
&=aaa(aaax) \tag{Associativity} \\
&=aaa(xaaa) \tag{Assumption}\\
&=(aaax)aaa \tag{Associativity}\\
&=(xaaa)aaa \tag{Assumption} \\
&=xaa^{5} \tag{Associativity}\\
&=xae \tag{$o(a)=5$} \\
&=xa \tag{Identity}
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: If $xa = ax$, then $xa^3 = xaaa = axaa = aaxa = aaax = a^3 x$, so $C(a) \subseteq C(a^3)$. The other containment requires an additional observation/trick.

Comment: Well, the other containment can be done the way OP showed :-) The line of reasoning there shows that if $x\in C(a^3)$, then $x\in C(a)$. In other words that $C(a^3)\subseteq C(a)$.

Comment: Your stab at it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of showing set equality is to take an element of one set and show that is also belongs to the other set. Then go the other way.

I'll take the easy one, showing that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^3)$.

Let $x \in C(a)$. That means that $xa = ax$. But then, since the group operation is associative, we have
$$
a^3x = aaax = aa(ax) = aa(xa) = a(ax)a = a(xa)a = (ax)aa = (xa)aa = xa^3
$$
so $x\in C(a^3)$.

Going the other way (i.e. showing that $C(a^3) \subseteq C(a)$) requires a small trick, but it goes along the same lines.

Comment: "since groups are associative" - Maybe you should rephrase this as "since the group **operation** is associative"

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$a^5 = e$ so $a = a^{5k+1}$, therefore

$$a = (a^3)^2$$

Comment: $a=a^6=(a^3)^2$

Comment: @lhf: Thanks, let me get that in!

Answer (score 2):

Try this roadmap:

- $C(a)=C(\langle a \rangle)$
- $ \langle a \rangle = \langle a^3 \rangle$

More generally, $C(a)=C(a^k)$ for all $k$ with $\gcd(k,o(a))=1$ because $ \langle a \rangle = \langle a^k \rangle$ in this case.