# Show that $C(a) = C(a^4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a \in G$ and $a$ has odd order, show that $C(a) = C(a^4)$.

Here, $C(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$.

I think this problem could be solved by making use of double inclusion; that is, Let $b\in G$, if $b\in C(a)$ then $b\in C(a^4)$ and viceversa. But I'm not sure how to get this result. I just need a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *HInt:* $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^4 \rangle$

Comment: Hint:  Note $(bab^{-1})^4=ba^4b^{-1}$, so if $bab^{-1}=a$, then..

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963598/given-oa-5-prove-ca-ca3

Comment: Why $-1$ in this question?